# Linux flash player settings dialog unclickable

Tags: linux, flash, flash-player

I'm using Slackware 13. When a flash app pops up the allow/deny dialog, I'm stuck because the buttons are unclickable. My adobe flash player version is 10,0,42,34. How can I fix this problem?

Edit: I'm using fluxbox. I'm using an acer notebook with a synaptics touchpad... both the touchpad and the mouse can't interact with the dialog.

Comment: whats your windowmanager?

Comment: I noticed this too, on opensuse. Are you using a laptop with a tracpad? i can only click it using a real mouse, not the tracpad (could be related to synpatics?)

Comment: It's incredible I stll have this bug

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem (stuck dialog/acer notebook/fluxbox) and found that after some random combination of clicking and tabbing, I could highlight various buttons. This didn't stop it being stuck but I managed to open adobe's help page, which has a flash app that will open just the settings manager - this worked for me:

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html#117118

also another link I found after that may be of use - it has some specific solutions to things that may trigger the problem:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=978212&page=3

Comment: Thanks. Going to the adobe settings page and enabling the "Always allow" option for the sites in questions worked perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution: I was using google chrome in ubuntu linux and I installed a Chrome extension called "Flashcontrol". Now the adobe flash player settings window doesn't appear anymore.